# Could someone help me with this json, I'm working in TS, but so far I haven't been able to parse it into a class(List)

Tags: json, typescript

{"numero1":{"numero":1,"titulo":"titulo1","urlletra":"urlletra1","urlmusic":"urlmusic1"}
,"numero2":{"numero":2,"titulo":"titulo2","urlletra":"urlletra2","urlmusic":"urlmusic2"}
,"numero3":{"numero":3,"titulo":"titulo3","urlletra":"urlletra3","urlmusic":"urlmusic3"}}

that Json is just an example, but it will have that behaviour... numero1 to numeroN

Comment: I'm working with angular

Comment: Where's your code, and what's the specific problem with it? What does Angular have to do with it?

Comment: i have the following code:
 this.http.get<Cancion[]>(`https://himnariosda.firebaseio.com/canciones.json`)
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length + '');
        data.forEach(value => {
          console.log(value);
        });
    }); 

and what I see in the console is [console.log]: "undefined". I

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly problem is..

json parsing is like this

```js
   let jsonString = '{"numero1":{"numero":1,"titulo":"titulo1","urlletra":"urlletra1","urlmusic":"urlmusic1"} ,"numero2":{"numero":2,"titulo":"titulo2","urlletra":"urlletra2","urlmusic":"urlmusic2"} ,"numero3":{"numero":3,"titulo":"titulo3","urlletra":"urlletra3","urlmusic":"urlmusic3"}}';

        let parsedJson = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        console.log(jsonParse);
```

or if you wanna set result type

```js
public list(): Observable<Company[]> {
        console.log('company')
        return this.httpService.get(`/company`);
    }
```

set return type to Observable like this

i don't know what exactly you want..
I hope it helps

Comment: I have this code:
 this.http.get<Cancion[]>(`https://himnariosda.firebaseio.com/canciones.json`)
    .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(data.length + '');
        data.forEach(value => {
          console.log(value);
        });
    }); 

inside the foreach I want to print each data, like this:
"numero":1,"titulo":"titulo1","urlletra":"urlletra1","urlmusic":"urlmusic1".

In other words I need to get numero1.(what's inside numero 1)... numeroN{what in numero N is}

Comment: i tried this and that data values are not array so you have to get keys Object.keys(data) .. like this than   Object.keys(data).forEach(p => {
            console.log(data[p]);
        })... it will help